# Django single login page for both rest_framework and admin console

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am making a Django application which uses rest_frameworks (under urlpattern '/api') and the admin console (for user and group management, under urlpattern '/admin'). Currently they both have their own login page. I want both of them to use the same login page (a single login URL), and if the user successfully logs in, then if it is a superuser redirect to the admin console, and if not a superuser then redirect to '/foo'.

I know you can insert a url pattern above the admin.site.urls to override its login (and logout) url patterns, but I want the login page to be '/login' not '/admin/login'.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve a shared login page for both your Django REST framework views and the Django admin console, you can create a custom authentication view and route all login requests to this view. Then, in your custom authentication view, you can check if the user is a superuser and redirect accordingly.

Here's a general approach you can follow:

1. Create a Custom Authentication View:

Create a new view for authentication, for example, in your views.py:

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def custom_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if user.is_superuser:
                return redirect('/admin/')
            else:
                return redirect('/foo/')
        else:
            # Handle invalid login credentials
            pass

    return render(request, 'custom_login.html')
```

2. Update URL Patterns:

Update your urls.py to include the custom login view and route login requests to it.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import custom_login

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('your_api_app.urls')),
    path('login/', custom_login, name='custom_login'),
]
```

This configuration assumes you have a separate urls.py for your API (your_api_app.urls). Adjust it based on your project structure.

Now, when users try to access the admin console or your REST API and are not authenticated, they will be redirected to the /login URL. After successful login, superusers will be redirected to /admin/, and others will be redirected to /foo/. Adjust the URLs and logic based on your specific requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately I don't think this fully answers the question. Within the admin.site.urls there are login/logout/etc paths. The same is true for rest_framework urls. I want to ensure these urls are pointing to my /login/ url so the user cannot access the standard login forms provided by those contributors.